# How to force an application to play through a selected audio output? Win8

Tags: windows-8, audio, volume-mixer

There are multiple programs and games that don't give me the option to choose which device I want it to playback through. I can change my default device and the program will change with it in realtime making it impossible for it to ONLY play through the audio output I want. Virtual Audio Cable allows me to replay the sound of an entire output through multiple audio devices but not specific programs.

I know of IndieVolume, but I can't use the trial and am not sure if it actually works on Windows 8. Is there some sort of alternative to it?